# JSQMessage with video and photo content

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I seeking, but cannot find information about this. Can I add video and photo in one bubble message cell?

I implemented sending attachments one by one.

```
JSQPhotoMediaItem *photoItem = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goldengate"]];   
JSQMessage *photoMessage = [JSQMessagemessageWithSenderId:kJSQDemoAvatarIdSquires displayName:kJSQDemoAvatarDisplayNameSquires media:photoItem];
```

But how to send it together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSQMessagesViewController does not currently support adding multiple media items (location, photo or video) to a single message. Have a look at [JSQMessage.h](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/JSQMessagesViewController/Model/JSQMessage.h):

```
+ (instancetype)messageWithSenderId:(NSString *)senderId displayName:(NSString *)displayName text:(NSString *)text;
+ (instancetype)messageWithSenderId:(NSString *)senderId displayName:(NSString *)displayName media:(id<JSQMessageMediaData>)media;
```

You would have to implement this functionality yourself or send them in separate messages.

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to do this you should try by making your own custom `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell` have a look [here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1380) might be helpful!

Comment: When posting a link, you should add also a summary of what the link says. If at some point the link becomes broken, your answer will not be helpful.